# aggregate a column by sum and another column by mean at the same time

Tags: r, aggregate

I want to use aggregate function on a date frame but sum one column and take average of another column.

Here is an example data frame

```
Manager   Category  Amount  SqFt
Joe           Rent     150   500
Alice         Rent     250   700
Joe      Utilities      50   500
Alice    Utilities      75   700
```

I cannot do something like below. Is there an easy way to do it ?

```
Avg_CPSF=aggregate(cbind(Amount,SqFt)~Manager,data=aaa,FUN=c(sum,mean)
```

Eventually I need

```
Manager  Amount   SqFT
Joe       200      500
Alice     325      700
```

so that I can calculate Cost per Square Foot by doing Amount/SqFT

Comment: There are just too many posts on this type of aggregation that a search on SO couldn't have gotten past you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Here are some that I like (all assuming we're starting with a `data.frame` named "mydf"):

Using `ave` and `unique`

```
unique(within(mydf, {
  Amount <- ave(Amount, Manager, FUN = sum)
  SqFt <- ave(SqFt, Manager, FUN = mean)
  rm(Category)
}))
#   Manager Amount SqFt
# 1     Joe    200  500
# 2   Alice    325  700
```

---

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)
DT[, list(Amount = sum(Amount), SqFt = mean(SqFt)), by = "Manager"]
#    Manager Amount SqFt
# 1:     Joe    200  500
# 2:   Alice    325  700
```

---

Using "sqldf":

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select Manager, sum(Amount) `Amount`, 
      avg(SqFt) `SqFt` from mydf group by Manager")
```

---

Using `aggregate` and `merge`:

```
merge(aggregate(Amount ~ Manager, mydf, sum), 
      aggregate(SqFt ~ Manager, mydf, mean))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `summarise` function with `ddply` in the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mtcars,.(cyl),summarise,TotalWt=sum(wt),AveHP=mean(hp))
  cyl TotalWt     AveHP
1   4  25.143  82.63636
2   6  21.820 122.28571
3   8  55.989 209.21429
```